# How to verticly align an object

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm using a table which contains an H3 inside.
Inside that H3 there is a google search bar.
Now the google search bar is alligned at the top of the H3.
How can I vertically allign it so it's centered?
This is what I have at the moment:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
<td id="Vak1.3"><h3>
                        <script type="">
                      (function () {
                          var cx = '013446364428343597193:qtxsarco2zs';
                          var gcse = document.createElement('script');
                          gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
                          gcse.async = true;
                          gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                                '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
                          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                          s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
                      })();
                        </script>
                        <gcse:search></gcse:search>
        </h3></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Try adding `style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;"` to your `<h3>`

Comment: Tried doing that, doesn't work ):

Comment: could you please post a fiddle..

Comment: I get exactly the same output without the style="display etc."

Comment: [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/81gkup47/) with your code. I can't see any problem with it. Clarify please?

Answer (score 0):

Generally spoken (without knowing your code), its no longer a good practice to design a website with a table. This doesn't mean that tables are bad in general. That said you could put your searchbar into a div:

```
<div id="container">your searchbar here..</div>
```

That div can be vertically (and horizontally) aligned easily with:

```
#container { 
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto;    
}
```

If you want to have only vertical alignment you can change:

```
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
```

But be patient that `position: absolute` is always related to the next parent element, which got the position element.

Comment: The Problem is, that I have a div in my h3 then. And then I get the warning: Div cannot be nested in H3.

Comment: @Kyle Oh my approach was deleting the h3 and use only that div container. If you still want to use your table structure you can remove that div and align the <tr> like i described

Comment: Changed the h3 for the div, but It still doesnt center, still gives the same old output...

Comment: @Kyle when i use your code, and give the <tr> the id container and use the css like described i see your stuff perfectly aligned at the center of the page...that div i used should be an alternative to your <table> approach

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/rp7ebb1c/1/
[reference](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html)

```css
#outer {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#outer[id] {
  display: table;
  position: static;
}
#middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
/* for quirk explorer only*/

#middle[id] {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  position: static;
}
#inner {
  position: relative;
  top: -50%
}
/* for quirk explorer only */
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="middle">
    <div id="inner">
      <script type="">
        (function () { var cx = '013446364428343597193:qtxsarco2zs'; var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true; gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx='
        + cx; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s); })();
      </script>
      <gcse:search></gcse:search>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```